# no extension after installation

Tags: magento-2.1, smtp

I installed free extension Magento 2 SMTP from [Mageplaza](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/download/)

```
php composer.phar require mageplaza/module-smtp
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

The entire installation went successful.
[image]

The panel "Mageplaza" appeared in the administration panel but can not see the SMTP Extension here. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Here is our back-end:
[image]

here is a demo version of how it should be:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
php bin/magento module:enable --all
```

Then run compilation again.